# Java - Problems Rounding Numbers

Tags: java, ruby

I wrote some Java code to generate pseudo-random numbers but I'm running into what I think are rounding problems getting it to match up with the same code in Ruby. Here's what I have in Java:

```
public class randTest {
  private final static Double A = Math.pow(5,13);
  private final static Integer S = 314159265;
  private final static Double minVal = Math.pow(2, -46);
  private final static Double maxVal = Math.pow(2, 46);
  private final static Double newMax = 10.0;

  private static Double r(Integer k) {
    Double powS = Math.pow(A, k) * S;
    Double xk = powS % maxVal.intValue();
    Double result = minVal * xk;
    System.out.println("k = " + k + ", pows = " + powS + ", xk = " + xk + ", result = " + result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

And the same thing in Ruby (my working reference implementation):

```
A = 5 ** 13
S = 314159265
MIN_VAL = 2 ** -46
MAX_VAL = 2 ** 46
NEW_MAX = 10

def r(k) # was generate_random
  powS = (A ** k) * S
  xk = powS % MAX_VAL
  result = MIN_VAL * xk
  puts "k = #{k}, pows = #{powS}, xk = #{xk}, result = #{result}"
  return result
end
```

For some reason, the output is vastly different (but the Ruby one is correct). Here's me calling r(4):

Java:

```
k = 4, pows = 6.9757369880463215E44, xk = 1.512592341E9, result = 2.1495230001278287E-5
```

Ruby:

```
k = 4, pows = 697573698804632158498861826956272125244140625, xk = 55279057169489, result = 0.785562650228954
```

Any idea as to why `powS` would be computed correctly in both but not `xk`? Note that on the Java version I needed to use `maxVal.intValue()` instead of `maxVal`, otherwise it returns zero. I've also tried replacing the `Double`s with `BigDecimal`s to no avail as well.

Comment: powS is reported differently in both. There's way more precision in the ruby version. This could be just the way you've printed it, but I suspect not.

Comment: Just as a general note: in Java you don't usually want to do math with Doubles, Integers, Longs et al. Use the primitives double, int, long, etc. instead; you should get a considerable speed boost. (But the only time I know of when you shouldn't be using primitives for math is when you need BigDecimals, so this advice might not apply here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is that Double can not hold the value you are trying to put into it, so it's getting truncated.

For large values like this, you need to use [java.math.BigDecimal](http://file:///D:/Documents/JDK-6-JavaDocs/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html), which allows for an arbitrarily large precision for decimal values.

Here's you're Java sample redone using BigDecimal:

```
public class RandTest {

    private final static BigDecimal A = new BigDecimal(5).pow(13);
    private final static BigDecimal S = new BigDecimal(314159265);
    private final static BigDecimal minVal = 
         new BigDecimal(2).pow(-46, new MathContext(100));
    private final static BigDecimal maxVal = new BigDecimal(2).pow(46);
    private final static BigDecimal newMax = new BigDecimal(10.0);

    private static BigDecimal r(Integer k) {
        BigDecimal powS = A.pow(k).multiply(S);
        BigDecimal xk = powS.remainder(maxVal);
        BigDecimal result = minVal.multiply(xk);
        System.out.println("k = " + k + ", pows = " + powS + ", xk = " + xk
                + ", result = " + result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

This version property returns the correct result you're looking for.

Comment: As does the exactly identical code posted by toolkit 10 minutes ago.

Comment: yep...comment didn't make it in fast enough :)

Comment: Upon further examination of tookit's code -- I'd argue that the version i posted is actually the correct one: He's still using Math.pow() in the assignments to BigDecimal, which returns a double and hence still risks losing precision.  In this case it seems to work fine, but I'm not sure if this is correctly defined behavior, or just a quirk of the VM.

Comment: Yes, I also like the use of pow in BigDecimal as opposed to in double. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You're getting truncation errors when you call `maxVal.intValue()`

Take a look at BigDecimal and BigInteger to achieve the same as your ruby snippet.

BTW: If you use [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) which sits on top of Java, then this uses BigDecimal out of the box.

Example code:

```
public class Rounding {
    private final static BigDecimal A = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.pow(5, 13));
    private final static int S = 314159265;
    private final static BigDecimal minVal = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math
            .pow(2, -46));
    private final static BigDecimal maxVal = BigDecimal
            .valueOf(Math.pow(2, 46));
    private final static BigDecimal newMax = BigDecimal.valueOf(10);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        r(4);
    }

    private static void r(final int k) {
        final BigDecimal powS = A.pow(k).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(S));
        final BigDecimal xk = powS.remainder(new BigDecimal(maxVal
                .toBigInteger()));
        final BigDecimal result = minVal.multiply(xk);
        System.out.println("k = " + k + ", pows = " + powS + ", xk = " + xk
                + ", result = " + result);

    }
}
```

Produces:

```
k = 4, pows = 697573698804632158498861826956272125244140625, xk = 55279057169489, result = 0.785562650228953900455100455956
```

Answer (score 2):

My Java is rusty, but doesn't intValue() go to a 32 bit int value?  2^46 would be too large to fit in there.

Comment: Java has 32-bit signed ints, so yeah. It looks like Ruby uses 64-bit integers (corresponding to Java's `long` type); is that true?

Answer (score 2):

When you call intValue() the double value will be cast to an int.

Java's Integer MAX_VALUE:

> A constant holding the maximum value an int can have, 2^31-1.

Your MAX_VAL:

> 2 ** 46

Even the long type cannot hold values big enough. I think as @toolkit says, you need the BigInteger class from the java.math package.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. In a situation like this, you'll need something like [BigInteger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) to make sure the values don't overflow their data types.
2. In a related issue, `maxVal.intValue()` returns 2147483647, far shy of the roughly 7.03E13 it should be.

Answer (score 1):

697573698804632150000000000000000000000000000

and

697573698804632158498861826956272125244140625

are not the same number.  You are losing precision in Java by having such a large number, where Ruby has arbitrary precision integer arithmetic.  Applying arithmetic operations to numbers that large in Java will result in [pseudo-]unpredictable results.